# Rust app to download, process, and upload files to S3

Tags: rust

I've written a small server app which grabs a token from another server, downloads JSON, then downloads files referenced in that JSON, processes them with a CLI `Command`, then uploads a result (some PDFs) to S3. My main question is in `main.rs`'s `thread::spawn(move || loop {` block, but I'll come back to that after posting the code.

```
// main.rs

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufWriter;
use std::net::IpAddr;
use std::str::FromStr;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::{thread, time};

use futures::join;
use futures::stream::{self, StreamExt};
use handlebars::Handlebars;
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use serde_json::json;
use tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::FmtSpan;
use uuid::Uuid;
use warp::Filter;

mod index_template;
mod models;
mod sys;
mod xfer;

lazy_static! {
    static ref FILTER: &'static str = env!("RUST_LOG");
    static ref IP: &'static str = env!("IP");
    static ref DOMAIN: &'static str = env!("DOMAIN");
    static ref USER: &'static str = env!("USER");
    static ref PASS: &'static str = env!("PASS");
}

type ReqResult<T> = Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> ReqResult<()> {
    let addr = IpAddr::from_str(*IP)?;
    let ack_vec: Vec<models::Acknowledgement> = Vec::new();
    let arc = Arc::new(Mutex::new(ack_vec));

    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .with_env_filter(*FILTER)
        .with_span_events(FmtSpan::CLOSE)
        .init();

    let cors = warp::cors::cors()
        .allow_any_origin()
        .allow_headers(vec!["content-type"])
        .allow_methods(vec![warp::http::Method::POST, warp::http::Method::GET])
        .build();

    let token = fetch_token().await.unwrap();

    let mut hb = Handlebars::new();
    hb.register_template_string("index.html", index_template::to_string())?;

    let hb = Arc::new(hb);
    let handlebars = move |with_template| index_template::render(with_template, hb.clone());

    // GET /create/:id
    let create = warp::get()
        .and(warp::path("create"))
        .and(warp::path::param())
        .map({
            let queue = arc.clone();

            move |id: u32| {
                let ack = models::Acknowledgement::new(id);
                let mut queue = queue.lock().unwrap();
                queue.push(ack);

                Ok(warp::reply::json(&id))
            }
        });

    // GET /json/:id
    let json = warp::get()
        .and(warp::path("json"))
        .and(warp::path::param())
        .map(|id: String| {
            let json = sys::JsonFile::from_id(id);

            warp::reply::json(&json)
        });

    // GET /log/:id
    let log = warp::get()
        .and(warp::path("log"))
        .and(warp::path::param())
        .map(|id: String| {
            let log = sys::LogEntry::from_id(id);

            warp::reply::json(&log)
        });

    // GET /
    let index = warp::get()
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .map({
            let queue = arc.lock().unwrap();
            let acks = queue.clone();

            move || index_template::WithTemplate {
                name: "index.html",
                value: json!({
                    "acks": acks,
                    "logs": sys::LogIndexEntry::from_most_recent(),
                    "stats": sys::LocalSystem::from_sys(),
                }),
            }
        })
        .map(handlebars);

    let routes = index
        .or(json)
        .or(log)
        .or(create)
        .with(cors)
        .with(warp::trace::request());

    thread::spawn(move || loop {
        let one_sec = time::Duration::from_secs(1);
        thread::sleep(one_sec);

        let queue = arc.clone();
        let mut queue = queue.lock().unwrap();

        while let Some(ack) = queue.pop() {
            let start = time::Instant::now();

            ack.init_log();
            let (mut ack, res) = fetch_json(ack, &token).unwrap();
            ack.append_to_log(format!("got json: {}", res.document.id));

            let doc = write_json(res.document, ack.uuid);
            ack.append_to_log(format!("wrote json: {}", doc.id));

            let rt = make_runtime();
            let res = rt.block_on(async {
                let assets = get_assets(&doc);
                let images = get_images(&doc);

                join!(assets, images)
            });
            ack.append_to_log(format!("got assets: {:?}", res));

            ack.call_xvfb(&token);
            ack.append_to_log(format!("made files: {:?}", ack.pdf_paths()));

            let rt = make_runtime();
            let res = rt.block_on(async { put_files(&ack).await });
            ack.append_to_log(format!("put files: {:?}", res));

            let rt = make_runtime();
            let res = rt.block_on(async { put_response(&ack, &token).await });
            ack.append_to_log(format!("put res: {:?}", res));

            let duration = start.elapsed();
            ack.append_to_log(format!("done and took {} seconds", duration.as_secs()));
        }
    });

    warp::serve(routes).run((addr, 4000)).await;
    Ok(())
}

fn make_runtime() -> tokio::runtime::Runtime {
    tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
        .enable_all()
        .build()
        .unwrap()
}

async fn fetch_token() -> ReqResult<models::Token> {
    let uri = format!("{}/api/v4/users/sign_in/", *DOMAIN);

    let json = json!({
        "email": *USER,
        "password": *PASS
    });

    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let res = client
        .post(uri)
        .json(&json)
        .send()
        .await?
        .json::<models::Token>()
        .await?;

    Ok(res)
}

fn fetch_json(
    ack: models::Acknowledgement,
    token: &models::Token,
) -> ReqResult<(models::Acknowledgement, models::DocumentResponse)> {
    let bearer = format!("Bearer {}", token.response);
    let uri = format!("{}/api/v4/documents/{}", *DOMAIN, ack.id);

    let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();
    let res = client
        .get(uri)
        .header("Authorization", bearer)
        .send()?
        .json::<models::DocumentResponse>()?;

    Ok((ack, res))
}

fn write_json(document: models::Document, uuid: Uuid) -> models::Document {
    let file_name = format!("./tmp/json/{}_{}.json", document.id, uuid);
    let json_file = File::create(file_name).expect("couldn't create json");
    let json_buf = BufWriter::new(json_file);
    let data = json!({ "document": document });

    serde_json::to_writer(json_buf, &data).expect("couldn't save json");
    document
}

async fn get_assets(document: &models::Document) {
    let snippets: Vec<models::Snippet> = document
        .components
        .clone()
        .into_iter()
        .map(|c| c.snippets)
        .into_iter()
        .flatten()
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let stream = stream::iter(snippets);
    stream
        .for_each(|s| async move {
            s.download().await.ok();
        })
        .await;
}

async fn get_images(document: &models::Document) {
    let images: Vec<models::FrameVariable> = document
        .frames
        .clone()
        .into_iter()
        .map(|f| f.frame_variables)
        .into_iter()
        .flatten()
        .filter(|v| {
            if v.key.is_some() {
                let key = v.key.clone();
                key.unwrap().starts_with("image")
            } else {
                false
            }
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let stream = stream::iter(images);
    stream
        .for_each(|s| async move {
            s.download().await.ok();
        })
        .await;
}

async fn put_files(ack: &models::Acknowledgement) -> (ReqResult<u16>, ReqResult<u16>) {
    let (high, low) = ack.pdf_paths();
    let (high_key, low_key) = ack.pdf_keys();
    let high_res = xfer::upload(high, high_key);
    let low_res = xfer::upload(low, low_key);

    join!(high_res, low_res)
}

async fn put_response(ack: &models::Acknowledgement, token: &models::Token) -> ReqResult<u16> {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let bearer = format!("Bearer {}", token.response);
    let uri = format!("{}/api/v4/documents/{}", *DOMAIN, ack.id);
    let (high, low) = ack.pdf_keys();

    let json = json!({
        "pdf_result": {
            "press_ready_url": high,
            "low_resolution_url": low,
            "created": ack.called
        }
    });

    let res = client
        .patch(uri)
        .json(&json)
        .header("Authorization", bearer)
        .send()
        .await?;

    Ok(res.status().as_u16())
}
```

```
// models.rs

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::process::Command;
use std::{fmt, fs, fs::OpenOptions};

use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use uuid::Uuid;

use crate::xfer;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct Acknowledgement {
    pub id: u32,
    pub uuid: Uuid,
    pub called: bool,
}

impl Acknowledgement {
    pub fn new(id: u32) -> Self {
        let uuid = Uuid::new_v4();
        Acknowledgement {
            id,
            uuid,
            called: false,
        }
    }

    pub fn init_log(&self) {
        let init_string = format!("added {}_{} to queue\n", self.id, self.uuid);
        fs::write(self.log_path(), init_string).expect("could not create log");
    }

    pub fn call_xvfb(&mut self, token: &Token) {
        self.append_to_log("called xvfb".to_string());

        let mut call = Command::new("podman")
            .args(&[
                "exec",
                "scribus",
                "xvfb-run",
                "-a",
                "scribus",
                "-ns",
                "-g",
                "-py",
                "./python/export.py",
                &self.id.to_string(),
                &self.uuid.to_string(),
                &token.response,
            ])
            .spawn()
            .expect("couldn't spawn cmd");

        call.wait().expect("couldn't wait cmd");
        self.called = true;
    }

    pub fn append_to_log(&self, line: String) {
        let mut log_file = OpenOptions::new()
            .append(true)
            .open(self.log_path())
            .unwrap();

        if let Err(e) = writeln!(&mut log_file, "{}", line) {
            println!("couldn't append to log: {}", e);
        }
    }

    fn log_path(&self) -> String {
        format!("./tmp/log/{}_{}.log", self.id, self.uuid)
    }

    pub fn pdf_paths(&self) -> (String, String) {
        let (high_key, low_key) = self.pdf_keys();
        let high_path = format!("./tmp/{}", high_key);
        let low_path = format!("./tmp/{}", low_key);

        (high_path, low_path)
    }

    pub fn pdf_keys(&self) -> (String, String) {
        let high_key = format!(
            "pdf/{}/{}/{}_{}_high.pdf",
            self.id, self.uuid, self.id, self.uuid
        );
        let low_key = format!(
            "pdf/{}/{}/{}_{}_low.pdf",
            self.id, self.uuid, self.id, self.uuid
        );

        (high_key, low_key)
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Acknowledgement {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}_{}", self.id, self.uuid)
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Deserialize, Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct Token {
    pub response: String,
}

#[derive(Clone, Deserialize, Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct DocumentResponse {
    pub document: Document,
}

#[derive(Clone, Deserialize, Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct Document {
    pub id: u32,
    client_code: String,
    colour1: String,
    colour2: String,
    pub components: Vec<Component>,
    pub frames: Vec<Frame>,
    template: String,
    template_page_size_preset: String,
    total_pages: u8,
}

#[derive(Clone, Deserialize, Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct Component {
    id: u32,
    pub snippets: Vec<Snippet>,
}

#[derive(Clone, Deserialize, Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct Snippet {
    id: u32,
    bucket: String,
    filename: String,
    idms: String,
    key: String,
    size: u64,
    page_number: i8,
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

impl Snippet {
    pub async fn download(&self) -> Result<u16, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        xfer::download(self.filename.to_string(), self.key.to_string()).await
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Deserialize, Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct Frame {
    id: u32,
    content_type: String,
    direction: String,
    div: String,
    frame_style: Option<Style>,
    pub frame_variables: Vec<FrameVariable>,
    height: Option<f64>,
    index: u8,
    name: String,
    page_number: i8,
    width: Option<f64>,
    x: Option<f64>,
    y: Option<f64>,
}

#[derive(Clone, Deserialize, Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct FrameVariable {
    id: u32,
    body: Option<String>,
    bucket: Option<String>,
    cmyk_colour: Option<HashMap<String, String>>,
    default_body: String,
    designator: String,
    html_tag: String,
    index: Option<f64>,
    pub key: Option<String>,
    lookup_id: Option<u32>,
    lookup_type: Option<String>,
    name: String,
    suffix: Option<String>,
    variable_style: Option<Style>,
}

impl FrameVariable {
    pub async fn download(&self) -> Result<u16, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        let uri = &self.key;

        match uri {
            Some(x) => {
                let key = x.split('?').into_iter().next().unwrap();
                xfer::download(key.to_string(), key.to_string()).await
            }
            None => panic!("no download"),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Deserialize, Debug, Serialize)]
struct Style {
    alignment: Option<String>,
    colour: Option<String>,
    font: Option<String>,
    line_height: Option<String>,
    size: Option<String>,
}
```

```
// sys.rs

use std::cmp;
use std::io::{prelude::*, BufReader};
use std::{fs, fs::File};

use chrono::{DateTime, Local};
use chrono_humanize::{Accuracy, HumanTime, Tense};
use rev_lines::RevLines;
use serde::Serialize;
use sysinfo::{ProcessExt, System, SystemExt};

use crate::models;

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct JsonFile {
    id: String,
    document: models::Document,
}

impl JsonFile {
    pub fn from_id(id: String) -> Self {
        let file_path = format!("./tmp/json/{}.json", id);
        let file = File::open(file_path).expect("no such file");
        let document: models::Document = serde_json::from_reader(file).unwrap();

        Self { id, document }
    }
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct LogEntry {
    id: String,
    output: Vec<String>,
}

impl LogEntry {
    pub fn from_id(id: String) -> Self {
        let file_path = format!("./tmp/log/{}.log", id);
        let file = File::open(file_path).expect("no such file");
        let output = BufReader::new(file)
            .lines()
            .map(|line| line.unwrap())
            .collect::<Vec<String>>();

        Self { id, output }
    }
}

#[derive(Eq, Serialize)]
pub struct LogIndexEntry {
    id: String,
    finished_at: String,
    humanized_finished_at: String,
    result: String,
    minutes_ago: u64,
}

impl LogIndexEntry {
    pub fn from_most_recent() -> Vec<Self> {
        let mut logs = vec![];

        for entry in fs::read_dir("./tmp/log").expect("no log dir") {
            let path = entry.unwrap().path();
            let metadata = fs::metadata(&path).unwrap();
            let timestamp = metadata.modified().expect("no timestamp");

            let timestamp_as_secs = timestamp.elapsed().unwrap().as_secs();
            if timestamp_as_secs < 7 * 24 * 3600 && metadata.is_file() {
                let file_name = String::from(path.to_str().unwrap());
                let id = file_name
                    .split('/')
                    .last()
                    .unwrap()
                    .split('.')
                    .next()
                    .unwrap();

                let file = File::open(path).unwrap();
                let lines = RevLines::new(BufReader::new(file)).expect("could not reverse log");
                let modified: DateTime<Local> = timestamp.into();
                let dt = Local::now() - modified;
                let ht = HumanTime::from(dt);

                logs.push(Self {
                    id: id.to_string(),
                    finished_at: modified.to_rfc3339(),
                    humanized_finished_at: ht.to_text_en(Accuracy::Rough, Tense::Past),
                    result: lines.into_iter().next().unwrap(),
                    minutes_ago: timestamp_as_secs / 60,
                });
            }
        }

        logs.sort();
        logs
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for LogIndexEntry {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &LogIndexEntry) -> Option<cmp::Ordering> {
        Some(other.cmp(self))
    }
}

impl Ord for LogIndexEntry {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &LogIndexEntry) -> cmp::Ordering {
        other.minutes_ago.cmp(&self.minutes_ago)
    }
}

impl PartialEq for LogIndexEntry {
    fn eq(&self, other: &LogIndexEntry) -> bool {
        self.minutes_ago == other.minutes_ago
    }
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct LocalSystem {
    instances: usize,
    percent_memory_used: String,
    load_avg_one: f64,
    load_avg_five: f64,
    load_avg_fifteen: f64,
}

impl LocalSystem {
    pub fn from_sys() -> Self {
        let mut sys = System::new_all();
        sys.refresh_all();

        let load_avg = sys.load_average();
        let instance_count = sys
            .processes()
            .iter()
            .filter(|(_, process)| process.name().contains("scribus"))
            .count();

        let percent_memory_used = format!(
            "{:.2}",
            (sys.used_memory() as f64 / sys.total_memory() as f64) * 100_f64
        );

        Self {
            instances: instance_count,
            percent_memory_used,
            load_avg_one: load_avg.one,
            load_avg_five: load_avg.five,
            load_avg_fifteen: load_avg.fifteen,
        }
    }
}
```

```
// xfer.rs

use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use s3::bucket::Bucket;
use s3::creds::Credentials;
use std::fs;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

lazy_static! {
    static ref BUCKET: &'static str = env!("BUCKET");
    static ref KEY: &'static str = env!("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID");
    static ref SECRET: &'static str = env!("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY");
}

async fn get_bucket() -> Result<Bucket, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let credentials = Credentials::new(Some(*KEY), Some(*SECRET), None, None, None)?;
    let region = "ap-southeast-2".parse()?;

    Ok(Bucket::new(*BUCKET, region, credentials)?)
}

pub async fn download(file_name: String, key: String) -> Result<u16, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let bucket = get_bucket().await?;
    let file_path = format!("./tmp/{}", file_name);

    if Path::new(&file_path).exists() {
        Ok(200)
    } else {
        let mut file_buf = PathBuf::from(&file_path);
        file_buf.pop();
        fs::create_dir_all(file_buf)?;

        let mut local_file = tokio::fs::File::create(file_path).await?;
        let status_code = bucket.get_object_stream(key, &mut local_file).await?;

        Ok(status_code)
    }
}

pub async fn upload(
    local_path: String,
    remote_path: String,
) -> Result<u16, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let bucket = get_bucket().await?;
    let mut local_file = tokio::fs::File::open(&local_path).await?;
    let status_code = bucket
        .put_object_stream(&mut local_file, remote_path)
        .await?;

    Ok(status_code)
}
```

```
// index_template.rs

use std::sync::Arc;

use handlebars::Handlebars;
use serde::Serialize;

pub struct WithTemplate<T: Serialize> {
    pub name: &'static str,
    pub value: T,
}

pub fn render<T>(template: WithTemplate<T>, hbs: Arc<Handlebars<'_>>) -> impl warp::Reply
where
    T: Serialize,
{
    let render = hbs
        .render(template.name, &template.value)
        .unwrap_or_else(|err| err.to_string());
    warp::reply::html(render)
}

pub fn to_string() -> &'static str {
    "<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>server</title>
                <script src='https://cdn.tailwindcss.com'></script>
            </head>

            <body>
                <div class='min-h-screen px-3 bg-gray-100 md:px-0'>
                    <div class='flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-full space-y-8'>
                        <div class='flex flex-col'>
                            <h1 class='text-2xl font-extrabold tracking-tight text-gray-900 py-2'>rpref</h1>
                            <h2 class='py-2'>
                                {{stats.instances}} instances running
                                <br />
                                {{stats.percent_memory_used}}% memory used
                                <br />
                                {{#each acks as |ack|}}
                                    queued: {{ack.id}}
                                    <br />
                                {{/each}}
                            </h2>

                            <div class='-my-2 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8'>
                                <div class='py-2 align-middle inline-block min-w-full sm:px-6 lg:px-8'>
                                <div class='shadow overflow-hidden border-b border-gray-200 sm:rounded-lg'>
                                    <table class='min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200'>
                                    <thead class='bg-gray-50'>
                                        <tr>
                                        <th scope='col' class='px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider'>ID</th>
                                        <th scope='col' class='px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider'>Finished</th>
                                        <th scope='col' class='px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider'>Result</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class='bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200'>
                                        {{#each logs as |log|}}
                                        <tr>
                                        <td class='px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap'>
                                            {{log.id}}
                                        </td>
                                        <td class='px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap'>
                                            {{log.humanized_finished_at}}
                                        </td>
                                        <td class='px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap'>
                                            <a class='underline' href='/log/{{log.id}}'>{{log.result}}</a>
                                        </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {{/each}}
                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>"
}
```

This is our first complete Rust service so I'm sure I've made a lot of mistakes. My main question, though, is about `main.rs`'s `thread::spawn(move || loop {` block: many of those calls are blocking because they often rely on the result of the previous call (downloading JSON requires a token for instance, and downloading assets requires JSON). That all works as expected.

I'm wondering if there's a way I can multithread some of this to process several requests at once.

Note that some assets are upwards of 10mb, and drawing and exporting the PDFs through Scribus requires reading those assets from the disk (and take between 10-20 seconds each). I thought about grouping the entire block in a Rayon pool, but several posts exist warning of the dangers of "heavy" file I/O and parallel processing.

**TL;DR:** can I parallelize a block of sync/async requests (even if one is a system `Command` which reads a decent amount of data into memory and takes up to 20 seconds)?